# How to hide the series name from showing in Charting Control

Tags: c#, charts

Hi Iam using the Microsoft Charting controls to show a simple bar graph with a single series. However, when the chart is rendered I can see the name of the series along with a defualt color on the right. Is there any way to hide this label from showing up

Comment: I also want the labels on X Axis to be displayed vertically

Comment: Figured that Every series is associated with a legend, is there any way to hide the legend text and the image

Comment: I hope the following link will be helpful for you. http://forums.silverlight.net/p/44237/370185.aspx

Answer (score 20):

You can hide series name very easy. In chart properties bar follow Series -> (...). Set IsVisibleInLegend property to false.

Comment: or by command chartElement.Series["Results"].IsVisibleInLegend = false;

Answer (score 2):

Adding labels above the bars:

```
    barchart.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

To remove labels above the bars:

```
    barchart.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the legend at all (for office applications):

```
shape.Chart.Legend.Clear();
```

Comment: Maybe chart1.Legends.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

The chart legend can be disabled in the Legend Collection Editor (the Chart Legends property) by setting Enabled to False.