# Checkbox to hide chart points instead of clearing them

Tags: vb.net, charts

I'm trying to make a `checkbox` to hide all series points, the problem is that I didn't find the `Visible` function for points, only `Clear`.

```
Grafico.Series(0).Points.Clear() ' Clears all the points, but I just want hide them
```

[image]

I want all the points to be hidden like that when I check my `checkbox`.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012718/selectively-hiding-series-in-a-c-sharp-chart ?

Comment: This disable the whole serie, but I don't want that... I just want to hide the labels... Not the line... @dr.null

Comment: OK. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707605/how-to-hide-label-of-data-points-in-line-chart and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404244/how-to-hide-the-series-name-from-showing-in-charting-control

Comment: It worked!... I tried before with "IsVisibleInLegend" but it only shows the legend in the right side... I used "Color.Transparent" to reach this... I thought about that, but thought only about "White" color not the "Transparent" color... Thanks a lot...